# AttributeError: 'CustomerHelper' object has no attribute 'requests_utility' src\helpers\customers_helper.py:23: AttributeError

Tags: python

from ssqaapitest.src.utilities.genericUtilities import generate_random_email_and_password
from ssqaapitest.src.utilities.requestsUtility import RequestUtility

class CustomerHelper(object):
def **int**(self):
self.requests_utility = RequestUtility()

```
def create_customer(self, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):

    if not email:
        ep = generate_random_email_and_password()
        email = ep['email']

    if not password:
        password = 'Password1'

    payload = dict()
    payload['email'] = email
    payload['password'] = password
    payload.update(kwargs)

    create_user_json = self.requests_utility.post('customers', payload=payload, expected_status_code=201)

    return create_user_json
```

expected result no error

Comment: Please fix your code formatting and explain how you're running it when you get this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your init function in your class `CustomerHelper`. You have `__int__(self)` it should be `__init__(self)`. This is what is creating the attribute error as that variable never gets initialized.